# Enforce power saving mode for powerbank charge

Tags: battery, charging, power-options

If I charge my phone from wall, disabling power saving is no problem.
But for a portable powerbank, I would still like power saving enabled.

How can I enforce Android to keep power saving on during powerbank charge?